# copy expense record to invoice detail through a button on a form in access

Tags: ms-access, vba

this is to add records from expenses record to an invoice details table using an invoice input form with sub forms
all related by "inv no"

i am coping info from 
Exp_Inv_input_Form
to
sub form = service atlan of main form = atlan inv main

i have been trying to use INSERT INTO with no luck and cant figure out where i am going wrong

```
    Private Sub btn_copy_Click()

Dim strSql As String
Dim IngID As Long

If Me.Dirty Then
        Me.Dirty = False
    End If

If Me.NewRecord Then
    MsgBox "select the record to duplicate."
Else
    With Me.RecordsetClone
        .AddNew
            !description_date = Me.TransactionDate
            !description = Me.description
            !hours = Me.Quantity
            !Price = Me.SubTotal
            !Total = Me.SubTotal
        .Update

        .Bookmark = .LastModified
        IngID = !inv_no

        If Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount > 0 Then
            strSql = "insert into [service atlan subform]([inv no], [description date], description, hours, Price, Billed )" _
                "SELECT " & lngID & " As NewID, description, Quantity, Total, from_exp " & _
                "FROM [service atlan] WHERE inv no = " & Me.inv_no & ";"
        DBEngine(0)(0).Execute strSql, dbFailOnError
    Else
        MsgBox "Main record duplicated, but there were no related records."
    End If
Exit_Handler:
    Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.description, , "cmdDupe_Click"
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Sub
```

now its telling me that there is a problem with my strSql
do i need to name the colums the same in both the tables as i was led to belive that its the sequance in which they are placed

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues with your sql statement. If you have blank space in column name, enclose with `[]` .

Also number of columns in the `insert` statement not matching with `select` statement

Also there is `,` after the table name in the `Insert` statement

Comment: thank you @s.jose ,  i have removed the  , and placed [ ] around those with blank spaces still no luck i am getting invalid strSql

Comment: I think you still have a problem with SQL. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

Comment: Thank you, i hadin´t noticed that  @s.jose . found a way for it to work, would you like to see all the code?

Answer (score 0):

I Have been messing around with the SLQ changed the table structure a bit and have had success my bigest problem was the structure of the Select statment

```
"INSERT INTO [Transaction List] ([TransactionDate], [Inv No], [Division], [MomsrevLookup], [Total], [Catagory]) " & _
        "Select """ & Me.[TransactionDate].Value & """, """ & Me.[inv no].Value & """,""" & Me.[Division].Value & """,""" & Me.revmoms.Value & """,""" & Me.[Inv_Total].Value & """,""" & Me.[Catagory].Value & """"
```

it is now coping selected rows from the form and pasting them to new records on another table